# How to write a custom match function for GTK entry completion?

Tags: rust, gtk

I would like to implement a fuzzy search for the GTK [`EntryCompletion`](https://gtk-rs.org/docs/gtk/struct.EntryCompletion.html) functionality via [`set_match_func`](https://gtk-rs.org/docs/gtk/trait.EntryCompletionExt.html#tymethod.set_match_func). There is very limited documentation.

Note that the code works with the default `EntryCompletion`.

The function should look something like this:

```rust
fn custom_entry_completion(store: &gtk::EntryCompletion, text: &str, ti: &gtk::TreeIter) -> bool {
    println!("{} // {:?}", text, ti);
    true
}
```

I want to embed it in something like this:

```rust
let completion_countries = gtk::EntryCompletion::new();
completion_countries.set_match_func(custom_entry_completion);
```

I would like a fuzzy match, but I think I will manage that part myself. Most helpful would be an example where the match is case insensitive or matching the last part of the string (or something). I am looking for a good example (preferably without unsafe) and/or good documentation.

So I need to take the value from the TreeIter and check if the match is as I want it to be. Hence, my question is how to get the item from the TreeIter with which to compare `text` against.

Comment: Can you expand on what you don't understand? You seemingly have the string (`text`) and you return a boolean; what more are you missing?

Comment: The ``text: &str` variable contains the text I am matching against. The `ti: &gtk::TreeIter` variable is the item inside the `gtk::ListStore::new(&col_types)`. So I need to take the value from the TreeIter and check if the match is as I want it to be. Hence, my question is how to get the item from the TreeIter with which to compare `text` against. (I have added this to the original question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Documentation

- [`EntryCompletionExt::get_text_column`](https://gtk-rs.org/docs/gtk/trait.EntryCompletionExt.html#tymethod.get_text_column)
- [`EntryCompletionExt::get_model`](https://gtk-rs.org/docs/gtk/trait.EntryCompletionExt.html#tymethod.get_model)
- [`TreeModelExt::get_value`](https://gtk-rs.org/docs/gtk/trait.TreeModelExt.html#tymethod.get_value)
- [`glib::value`](https://gtk-rs.org/docs/glib/value/index.html)

### An example

```rust
fn custom_entry_completion(store: &gtk::EntryCompletion, text: &str, ti: &gtk::TreeIter) -> bool {
    let tree_model = store.get_model().unwrap();
    let text_column = store.get_text_column();

    let ti_text_value = tree_model.get_value(ti, text_column);

    if ti_text_value.is::<String>() {
        let value = ti_text_value.get::<String>().unwrap();
        println!("{:?} // {:?}", text, value);
    } else {
        println!("{:?} // not a string", text);
    }

    true
}
```

Console output when used with the [entry_completion.rs](https://github.com/gtk-rs/examples/blob/master/src/bin/entry_completion.rs) example:

```
"adfs" // "France"
"adfs" // "Italy"
"adfs" // "Italy"
"adfs" // "Sweden"
"adfs" // "Sweden"
"adfs" // "Switzerland"
"adfs" // "Switzerland"
"adfssdf" // "France"
"adfssdf" // "Italy"
"adfssdf" // "Sweden"
"adfssdf" // "Switzerland"
```